# How to add a module getters in composition api?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I am using vue 2, installed composition api. How can I add Getters?
Usually:

```
  computed: {
...mapGetters("Auth", ["isLogged"])}
```

..........................................................................

```
setup() {
const title_app = ref("Name App");
const logout = () => {
  store
    .dispatch("Auth/logout")
    .then(() => {
      router.push({ name: "About" });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

return {
  title_app,
  logout,
};
```

},

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import { computed } from 'vue'

export default {
  setup (props, { root }) {
    const isLogged = computed(() => root.$store.Auth.getters.isLogged)

    return {
      isLogged
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "TypeError: root.$store.Auth is undefined"

Comment: try to debug it, which part of it coming undefined.

Comment: `root.$store.getters['Auth/isLogged']` would work